# How do I easily make a "joke OS"?

Tags: linux

I do not want to build a full-fledged super popular awesome new linux distro. What I'm searching for is a tool to take an existing linux distro and modify the .iso so I can change basic objects and functions such as default wallpaper and the like. If you want an example of a joke os, look up biebian. Preferably, the tool can run on linux without 3rd party programs like WINE.

Comment: The answers on that "duplicate" are probably overcomplicated for this simple case

Comment: Top hit on Google suggests https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD

Answer (score 3):

Just put

```
watch -n 10 alert "Wakka Wakka!"
```

into the .bashrc, much easier to distribute.

Comment: or check out [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback).  Remastersys is kaput and the only other option I know of is $50.  With Systemback you can setup an OS just as you want it to be, then turn it into an .iso.

But I still say the first way is best.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it, but a friend of mine did this, with success:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso